# Tools to migrate TFS2005 source code (w history) to TFS2010

Tags: migration, team-foundation-server

I need to migrate specific source code folders from a TFS 2005 server to a new installation of TFS 2010. These specific source folders need to migrate the version history as well.

What tools or process are available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TFS Integration Tool is what I ended up using.   Huge learning curve.  Great (if hard to find) documenation.

http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/